# Error when JSON contains Chinese

Tags: json, post, asynchttpclient, chinese-locale

`AsyncHttpClient` POSTs JSON data, if I have Chinese in the JSON the response is

`http 400 The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ()`

My server is a Rest server. Can anyone tell me how this error happened as my server can receive Chinese correctly?

```
    StringEntity entity =null;
    try {
        entity = new StringEntity(jsonEntity==null ?null : jsonEntity.toString());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    client.post(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), entity, "application/json", responseHandler);
```

Comment: Is the client using an encoding that will work for Chinese characters, such as UTF-8?

Comment: Thanks, I have resloved the problem. using the below code :entity = new StringEntity((jsonEntity==null ?null : jsonEntity.toString()),"UTF-8");  change the encoding to utf-8